# Benefits of enabling "SharePoint server Publishing " site feature inside my sub site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, site, publishing

I have created a sub site of type Team site, now by defualt the new subsite will have the following site content :-

[image]

then i have enabled the "SharePoint Server Publishing" site feature for the sub-site , where i got the following additional libraries:-

[image]

now i can not feel the benefits of these new libraries , for example before activating the publishing feature , when i want to add an image to a page it will be saved under the "site assets" library, while after enabling the feature it will be saved under the "Images" library. so can anyone adivce what are the benefits of enabling the ""SharePoint Server Publishing"" inside the subsites ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to quote myself on this reply I gave to a similar question

[What are the factors that govern the decision of whether to choose publishing or collaboration (teamsite) template for new site collection?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101430/what-are-the-factors-that-govern-the-dicission-of-whether-to-choose-publishing-o/101441#101441)

- Site Pages (from the team site) contain Wiki Pages.
- Pages (from the publishing site features) contains Article pages and similar pages, that can be used as a base for news rolls with content query/search web parts.

When you activate publishing features you get to use also Image renditions (new in 2013) to resize and crop properly images without any need for an external software.

Comment: now i did a test inside my Team site where i have enabled the "publishing infrastructure " site collection feature, and i got all the new libraries and features added, then i deactivate the feature again, where all the new libraries and options are stil there.. so does this mean that i can benefit from the publishing infrastructure feature even if i deactivate it ?? or this is not the case?

Comment: The libraries will remain there even tho you deactivate the feature since they are physical entities, but for instance some functions will not work (Image renditions for example). If you do not need them any longer, you can delete the libraries you do not need.

Answer (score 2):

This feature is really useful if you want to control what should be publish on your site, this feature enable to use the content approval workflow.

> SharePoint includes a set of features that enables you to author and
>   publish rich webpages for your intranet or Internet. These features
>   are housed within the SharePoint Publishing Infrastructure and must be
>   activated prior to use. You can activate them at either the site
>   collection or site level.
>   https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-publishing-features-479677a6-8b33-4ac7-907d-071c1c7e4518?CorrelationId=fddb8cb5-9304-47cb-b69b-e7ceae6d8ccc&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

[Overview of publishing to Internet, intranet, and extranet sites in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635881.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint's publishing infrastructure provides an enhanced way to create and store information displayed through the site's web pages. The publishing infrastructure is only available on the pay versions of SharePoint is can be enabled by activating features at both the site collection and site level.
Two features are responsible to enabling publishing on a SharePoint site. The first feature is the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature that is activated at the site collection features. Once the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature is activated, then the SharePoint Server Publishing site feature can be activated on sites within the site collection.

https://www.webucator.com/tutorial/advanced-microsoft-sharepoint/sharepoint-server-publishing-infrastructure.cfm

http://www.sharepointchick.com/archive/2011/06/23/sharepoint-publishing-features-functionality.aspx